# Java TLS Socket Write Fails to Detect Connection Reset

Tags: java, sockets, tls1.2

I am struggling with timely detection of connection resets on a Java TLS socket.

I am dealing with a syslog-over-TLS client that is loosing messages. The syslog client sends messages as they arrive and for that purpose keeps a single TLS socket open unless there is an error in which case it discards the socket and opens a new connection.

For investigating this problem I send the same type and size of message over and over again.

What happens is the following:

1. Start client
2. 1st message arrives - new socket is opened and message is transferred successfully to remote syslog (code below)
3. Idle for 15 minutes
4. 2nd message arrives - existing socket is used to send message; tcp connection reset is received but no exception is thrown; the message is lost
5. 3rd message arrives shortly after - write to socket immediately fails with an exception: Connection Reset; client opens new socket and successfully sends message

The code for sending the messages is (too?) simple:

```
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
out.write(syslogFrame);
out.write(msgBytes);
out.flush();
```

Why do I not receive an exception right on the second message at the latest for the second write operation in the code above? And how can I make sure I do?

The message is significantly larger than the MTU and the I/O graph shows quite clearly that the 2nd message does not even make it over the wire:

[image]

The full trace: The connection is established at packet #2. Packets up to #27 are the transmission of the first message. #28, #29, #30 is the beginning of the 2nd message answered by the connection reset. No exception is raised in the Java code at this point. The socket-write operation returns without error but the message is lost. The write operation for the 3rd message now receives the Connection Reset exception, which triggers the client code to re-establish the connection in packets #33 ff and the 3rd message then goes over the wire.

[image]

My OSes running the client are Linux Mint 18.3 (Kernel 4.10.0-38-generic) with Oracle JDK 1.8.0_172 and 10.0.2; CentOS Linux 7.5.1804 (Kernel 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64) and Oracle JDK 1.8.0_172.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually inherent to all simplex protocols implemented on TCP. And it gets somewhat aggravated by the fact that writes in Java tend to return before any bytes are actually pushed down the TCP stack. Not even on `flush()`. So the signaling is unreliable by design.

The only reliable way to determine the health of a socket connection is by reading from it. But with a simplex protocol there is nothing to read. Which is why rsyslog implements the [RELP protocol](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/relp.html) which adds a backchannel over which application level ACK/NAK messages are sent.

Comment: Writes in Java are not non-blocking unless you're using a `Channel` in non-blocking mode, and he isn't.

Comment: @user207421, you are right, it is not non-blocking. Wrong wording. I updated the wording.